# how can i change the text-color of the last button in my mobile view menu?

Tags: wordpress, css, css-selectors

I am using wordpress publisher template.
The color of the mobile menu should be `#051039` except the last one which is like the button, my problem is the background color of button is same `#051039`, so I want to change it to white.
I try to solve this problem by adding extra css code to the id of the link:

```
#menu-item-430 {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #051039;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

but nothing happened. How can I fix it?
This is my site:
https://ijimfang.com

Comment: You can use media query to apply css only on mobile:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: the main problem is the button-text color not changing!

Comment: it is because inside the `#menu-item-430` div there is another child `<a>` with a color property. so you will have to apply color to that `<a>` tag

Comment: Thanks. kindly up vote this answer, So that it will be use full for our followers.

Comment: Thanks @hamidkhd13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this style**

```
.rh-cover .rh-c-m .resp-menu li:last-child > a { color: #fff !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Please add this code to style.css file of your currently activated theme.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul#resp-navigation li:last-child{
        text-align: right;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #051039;
    }
    ul#resp-navigation li:last-child a{
        color: #fff !important
    }
}
```